# GL_Invalid_Operation in OpenGL applications

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-compat

I am currently wiring an OpenGL application and am getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. The whole GL is scattered among several files and its hard to create an example out of it, but I have created an OpenGL trace using `apitrace`. This is one chunk that created the error:

```c
glMatrixMode(mode = GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glViewport(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1190, height = 746)
glOrtho(left = 0, right = 1190, bottom = 0, top = 746, zNear = 0, zFar = 128)
glBegin(mode = GL_QUADS)
glColor4f(red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
glVertex3f(x = 1190, y = 746, z = 0)
glColor4f(red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
glVertex3f(x = 0, y = 746, z = 0)
glColor4f(red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
glVertex3f(x = 0, y = 100, z = 0)
glColor4f(red = 0.5, green = 0.5, blue = 0.5, alpha = 1)
glVertex3f(x = 1190, y = 100, z = 0)
glEnd()
glGetError() = GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

Has someone any idea on this?

Comment: Probably would be best if glGetError() was added before this chunk and also after glBegin() to determine if the error isn't from elsewhere and if `glBegin` / `glEnd` is supported.

Comment: Well, `apitrace` can replay files using a debug context (and iirc, `qapitrace` even does so by default), so both the origin and the reason for the error should be very easy to spot.

Answer (score -1):

GL_QUADS is deprecated since version 3 and removed since version 3.1.

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Quads

Comment: This is [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL). `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences are deprecated, too. `GL_QUADS` and `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences are removed in a core profile context but still valid in a compatibility profile context. That's not the point here, see [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).

Comment: Fair point, if OP updates with more information to confirm that their implementation supports legacy, I'll remove the answer.

Comment: Ummm I am no expert in GL. I create the Context in Linux using `GLX`. What information can I provide for a better understanding?

Comment: If this is a new application and you don't have any particular reason to support legacy, you'd probably be better off just targeting the version 3 API instead (the old stuff is deprecated for over a decade now).

Comment: i am currently porting a GTK application from GTKGLext (as it is not packaged for some distros we target) to GLX and EGL. Normally I would only use EGL, but the nvidia driver has a bug with it, so I need to use a GLX fallback. I dont want to change the GL drawing code if possible